# Spark AR keep plane facing user/camera

Tags: javascript, instagram, spark-ar-studio

Is there a way to keep plane nested inside a plante tracker & placer always facing to the camera / user?

I already tried setting the rotationY by combining the camera world rotation with the placer rotation but no success so far.

```
plane.transform.rotationY = camera.worldTransform.rotationY.add(placer.worldTransform.rotationY);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need? In my case the plane was under the plane tracker hierarchy.

```
plane0.worldTransform.rotation = planeTracker.worldTransform.lookAt(camera.worldTransform.position).rotation;
```